# Cannot create GroupBox in mfc app

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

```
CPanel * CWnd;
...
CPanel = new CWnd();
CPanel->Create(TEXT("STATIC"), L"PANELпанелька", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE|BS_GROUPBOX,
    CRect(100, 100, 300, 300), this, 1234);
CPanel->SetWindowTextW(L"XFDSF");
```

After compiling I get just a square with 1px grey border with no title. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Groupbox is CButton. This one works:

```
CButton *m_button;
m_button = new CButton();
CRect m_rec(10,10,150,80);
m_button->Create(L"Select",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_GROUPBOX,m_rec, this, ID_BUTTON1);
```

Comment: YOU're GREAT! THNX VERY MUCH